# I have just searched for a usb Y cable to power my HDD from another power source but also transfer data to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: power, usb-power

So here the Y cable I'm thinking of buying it's to connect my Western digital Elements HDD to a different power-source rather than using the Raspberry Pi as an only usb power  but also using the other USB to allow for my Pi to mount the HDD, will it work?

http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/maplin-usb-30-a-to-micro-b-dual-power-cable-3m-a66qc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is going to back feed power to whatever it is attached to.

I purchased a powered USB hub from eBay that is then plugged into my Rasberry Pi2. I have a USB2 sata docking station with a NTFS formatted drive in it that plugs into the hub, THEN into the PI. I find that my pi runs very stable with a low load on the built in hub, and a heavy load on the powered hub. I'm now looking at purchasing a USB3 Dock for flexibility with other laptops.

This is the unit I purchased:
[USB2 7 Port powered hub pi compatible](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/New-High-Speed-SQ-7-Port-USB-2-0-HUB-External-Power-Supply-/221264418145?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3384631561)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does the data transfer over the powered usb hub to the pi. And you were right it didn't work it back-fed

Comment: how did you connect your hdd into the hub and then connect it to the Pi? A picture would help thanks

Comment: I have an older USB2 sata dock Thermaltake that I have plugged into the powered usb hub. Like this one: http://www.ebay.ca/itm/like/201106993026?limghlpsr=true&hlpv=2&ops=true&viphx=1&hlpht=true&lpid=116

I used these instructions http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/